# XML Error: error: not well-formed (invalid token) in splash screen (React Native)

Tags: android, xml, react-native, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to implement a Splash Screen in my React application, but at the debug time, the splash file has an error: error: not well-formed (invalid token)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

<layer-list xmlns:='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'>
  <item android:drawable='@color/primary' />
  <item
  android:width='200dp'
  android:height='200dp'
  android:drawable='@drawable/icon'
  android:gravity='center'
  /> 
</layer-list>
```

> Error Message:

```
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  C:\Users\leand\AppTCC\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\background_splash.xml:3: error: not well-formed (invalid token).
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<layer-list xmlns:='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'>
```

to

```
<layer-list xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'>
```

to properly define the `android` namespace prefix and eliminate your error.